# Can't connect to windows via ssh

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh, cygwin

I downloaded cygwin and ran ssh-host-config. I'm trying to connect using

```
ssh -l micah myserver
```

it then says

```
micah@myserver's password:
```

I enter the same password I use to log into windows and it says

```
Permission Denied, please try again.
```

After the third try it says:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? Do I need to generate an ssh key on the client and add it somewhere on the server?

Comment: BWAH!!! My stupid password was incorrect....

Comment: Please post that as an answer and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able. There's even a [badge for self answering](http://serverfault.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Answer (score 2):

This may save someone time in the future no matter how simple it seems...

The userid will be case sensitive - so if you are used to logging into windows chris even though it is actually Chris, that will not work when you try to ssh in, an easy edit in /etc/passwd will suffice, also make sure user id is case sensitive in Windows service Log on tab

Answer (score 0):

check this page out, it may explain what to try to fix this issue.

http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh#gen-keys

seems like you do need a publickey installed for your session. I would say yes you do.

OR

comment out the line in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

and

restart `sshd` service.